# Failed to find style 'listMenuViewStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported android's BluetoothLeGatt sample project using android studio's "import an Android code sample" option, but without making any edits I immediately have render errors in both menu xml files: "Failed to find style 'listMenuViewStyle' in current theme". I noticed that the project has a "base-template-styles.xml" instead of just "styles.xml" which was odd, but I have no idea how to resolve this considering it's unedited Android code. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you do a project-wide search for that string?

Comment: It only occurs in R.java (4 times)

Comment: If that is the only location, then you need to clean & rebuild the project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find style 'listMenuViewStyle' in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590620/failed-to-find-style-listmenuviewstyle-in-android-studio)

Comment: Just tried that, didn't fix the error and listMenuViewStyle still doesn't appear anywhere but R.java

Comment: As far as I can tell, that sample should work fine. Try cloning the source. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Comment: Cloned it from github and opened that but it also has the error

Comment: Hmm. I'd open a github issue there, then

Comment: See some answers in: [Android Studio 1.2.1.1 - Failed to find style 'textViewStyle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358549/android-studio-1-2-1-1-failed-to-find-style-textviewstyle)